# Casting `f32::MAX` to `u128` results in unexpected value

Tags: casting, rust

Executing this code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9844bcb21bad2831d7898ac16b5f280a)):

```
println!("u128 max:    {}", u128::max_value());
println!("f32 max:     {}", std::f32::MAX);
println!("f32 as u128: {}", std::f32::MAX as u128);
```

... prints:

```
u128 max:    340282366920938463463374607431768211455
f32 max:     340282350000000000000000000000000000000
f32 as u128: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440
```

Judging from this output, we can deduce that `u128::max_value() > f32::MAX` and that `f32::MAX` is an integer (without fractional part). Indeed, [Wikipedia agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) with the max values and says that `f32::MAX` is (2 − 2<sup>−23</sup>) × 2<sup>127</sup> which is slightly less than 2<sup>128</sup>. Given that, I would think that `f32::MAX` is exactly representable as `u128`. But as you can see, casting it via `as` gives an entirely different value.

**Why does the result of the cast differ from the original value?**

(*I know that floats are very strange beasts and all. But I hope that there is an answer to this question that contains more information than "floats are strange duh"*)

Comment: floats are strange duh

Comment: (2 − 2<sup>−23</sup>) × 2127 *is* 340282346638528859811704183484516925440. It looks like `println!` may round floats when printing them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to the formatting of the float when you are printing it. It seems by default the formatter will only show 8 significant figures when printing floats. Explicitly specifying the precision in the format string will yield the same results for line 2 and 3.

```
println!("u128 max:    {}", u128::max_value());
println!("f32 max:     {:.0}", std::f32::MAX);
println!("f32 as u128: {}", std::f32::MAX as u128);
```

Outputs:

```
u128 max:    340282366920938463463374607431768211455
f32 max:     340282346638528859811704183484516925440
f32 as u128: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440
```

Comment: Since single-precision floats only have about 8 siginificant digits, the remaining digits are generally just noise – they don't contain any actual information, and mainly result from the conversion between number systems. So defaulting to that number of significant digits makes sense to me, though of course the exponential number format also makes more sense for floating-point numbers.

Comment: It is not a fixed number of digits. It maximizes the number of zeros so that when the printed number is rounded to the nearest `f32` it results in the original float. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df6817c1a5c381ae6e90765185a4bbbd